# CloudFront support for multiple S3 buckets

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront setup from which I want to serve static file content placed in multiple S3 buckets ( can go to more than 100). 
Is there a way to accomplish this in CloudFront? 
I guess one way is to create Origin Behaviours in CloudFront but configuring the same for more than 100 buckets will be difficult to manage.
I am not sure if I can accomplish this using Lamda Edge Function. If its possible it will be great to get more clarity on this.

thanks

Comment: your cost w/ Lambda@Edge would become astronomical with this pattern (BEWARE). you can do it, but i would stay clear

Comment: Do you really have 100 of paths going to different bucket ? Is there any limitation in having prefixes in the same bucket ? as @LostJon mentioned, lambda would cost money but here is an example: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/ , you can have origin request function to read uri filed and choose origin accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @LostJon is there any way I can get calculate lamda pricing?

Comment: lots of theoretical cost analysis. based on your anticipated traffic and https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/#Lambda.40Edge_Pricing_Details, you should be able to determine a cost.

Comment: might be worth looking at the example under it, and multiplying by 100 for your anticipated cost with 10mil requests

Comment: I am trying out the mentioned example. I keep getting 403 error when I access the CloudFront URL. Any idea how can I debug this? I have no clue how to go about debugging this.